# Remote script for multiple machines

Tags: shell-script, scripting, remote-management, remote-control

I have multiple CentOS machines on a network and I need to be able to push one script at a time to all of the machines at once.

I have looked at something like Atera, but that is for windows, is not free nor open source and it also has way too much functionality.

If anyone can please give me a recommendation on what software I can use for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend Ansible about that. With Ansible developed by Redhat, you can send and configure commands to multiple servers from one place.

I can also recommend Terraform. Many practices about both applications are available on the internet pages.

You can also check out: Puppet, Chef, Salt.

Comment: Oh my (red)hat I can't believe I forgot about not just one, but both of those... Thank you very much